Use Coq code from Github repos
I'm writing some Coq code for which I would need these results and these ones.
I had the feeling I had to use opam but, even if the repo about Arrow's theorem contains an opam file, the command opam list -a doesn't return it.
To sum up, I'm a bit lost and don't manage to put together what I've seen on the internet.

Here is example guidance that should cover most cases:
https://gitlab.inria.fr/fbesson/itauto#installation
Though, on Windows, you either go for one of the WSL/Cygwin/MinGW, or can only git-clone then work with it as you are already doing with your own developments (typically, since the command-line tools work, including 'coqc', that is compiling from the command-line, possibly in a batch emulating 'make', or one file at a time from CoqIDE).

Thanks. I'm on Linux. I look at that.
